# J2me web service call and error java.rmi.ServerException:

Tags: java, java-me, jboss, webservice-client, midlet

Hello i am creating a J2ME application in which i need to call a web service for processing
i am encrypting data and then calling web service

my code is working perfect on my Linux(Fedora) but not working on my windows and actual mobile
Server is using JBoss and EJB

Code :-

```
CryptoEngine.setEncryptionKey("ROFTALPTNEMYAP1A");                      

String IMEI = "IMEI="+txtIMEI.getString();
String phoneno = "phoneNumber="+txtPhoneNo.getString();

System.out.println(IMEI);
System.out.println(phoneno);

String en = CryptoEngine.encryptString(phoneno + ";" + IMEI);
System.out.println(en);
byte[] ben = en.getBytes();
System.out.println("En = " + en);
String BaseEn = new String (Base64.encode(ben));


System.out.println("Base64 En = " + BaseEn);
form.append(en);

/*
 * Code For webservice
 */
A1Stubs.A1MobileService_Stub stub = new A1Stubs.A1MobileService_Stub();
stub._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://41.86.150.26:9090/A1Payment-A1Payment-ejb/A1MobileService");
String response = stub.getKey(BaseEn);
form.append("Reached After Web-service Called");
System.out.println(response);

/*
 * End  of Web Serivce
 */

byte[] baseDecode = Base64.decode(response);
String Decrypt = CryptoEngine.decryptString(new String(baseDecode));
System.out.println(Decrypt);
item.setText("Encrypted Text: \n"+en+"\n\n BASE64 Encryption: \n"+new String(Base64.encode(ben))+"\n\n Response of Web-Service : \n"+response+"\n\n BASE64 Decryption : \n"+new String(baseDecode)+"\n\n Decrypted Text : \n"+Decrypt);
display.setCurrent(form);
```

on windows machine i am getting following error after calling web service

```
java.rmi.ServerException: 
[Code:   env:Server] 
[String: String index out of range: -1] 
        at com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.OperationImpl.setupResStream(OperationImpl.java:380)
        at com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.OperationImpl.invoke(OperationImpl.java:236)
```

why i am facing this problem????

Comment: post code and there is problem at your server code

Comment: actually server side is not created by me its already created and working but giving me error response

Comment: @org.life.java i am not getting if there is problem then why this is not giving error in my Linux(Fedora)

Comment: i have added my code i am getting error at line of calling web service, String response = stub.getKey(BaseEn);

Comment: CryptoEngine is my class which will encrypt and decrypt data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a problem server-side. This type of error indicates that there is nothing to read in the stream you received. You should check the server logs to see what happened.

Comment: @Valentine Rocher are you sure this is server side issue because i am not having rights of server and if this is server issue then i have to talk to higher authority

Comment: seems like it, yeah. I can't be __sure__, that's just what it seems to me. Without more information, that's all I can say. Try to debug your program, and see where the error comes, and what is in your variables at this moment.

Comment: i have debug application i am getting error at , String response = stub.getKey(BaseEn);

Comment: As I said, the place of error and the kind of message indicates the stream you're getting info from, the one used by the stub, is empty. So, there either a connexion, either an error with the request. It could be server-side, or maybe you're sending the wrong data.